# Arduino MKR WIFI 1010: WiFi101 shield: NOT PRESENT

Tags: wifi

A few days ago I received my MKR WIFI 1010 including MKR2UNO Board. Vin Connected via power plug, and USB to PC connected as well. The Blink example works fine. Or any example excluding WIFI. 
I tried to use examples in "Examples>WIFI101" like Firmware Version or Scan Networks. It always comes back with "WiFi101 shield: NOT PRESENT"
I even attempted to tun "Tools>FirmwareUpdater" By testing the connection, it comes back with "Programmer not responding". I read somewhere that a double-tap on the reset button might help. After doing this and a click on "refresh-list", I see two ports displayed. A click on the new port and "Test connection" Same result "Programmer not responding".
On the MKR 1010 I see three LED's on: They are labeled "ON", "L" and "CHRG" which is slow flashing as well.
I seem not to be able find tutorials or any help really pertaining to MKR wifi 1010. Since this board is different from MKR WIFI 1000, the examples there are not helping.
I also cant find any layout and explanation pf the on-board LED's. Very frustrating!
I hope, any of you can give me some help.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The right WiFi library for the MKR1010 is WiFiNINA. You can install it in Library Manager.

the schema of the board is [here](https://content.arduino.cc/assets/MKRWiFi1010V2.0_sch.zip)

from variant.h

```
// LEDs
// ----
#define PIN_LED     (6u)
#define LED_BUILTIN PIN_LED
```

you can get support from developers on [Arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?board=121.0)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. However, running an example from "Examples>WifiNINA>ScanNetworks" produces only "Communication with WiFi module failed!" error. What now??? –

Comment: official support https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?board=121.0

Answer (score 1):

The WiFi101 is a shield for the Uno using the ATWINC1500 module.

The MKR1010 is a complete board with an ESP32-based module.

The two are completely different. You can't use the library for one on the other.

You need the WiFiNINA.h library which is available in the library manager, or from Github [here](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/WiFiNINA).

Comment: the board is not in beta boards, but in 1.6.19. the WiFiNina library is in Library Manager

Comment: @Juraj You changed your mind then, and deleted your comment?

Comment: :-) yes. do not trust anyone. I was on a phone. I am looking into it deeper now on a computer

Comment: the NINA module (ESP32) is connected over SPI. the WiFiNina library uses SPI. the libraries are not so different. the WiFi1010 later renamed to WiFiNina is not so big rewrite of WiFi101.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. However, running an example from "Examples>WifiNINA>ScanNetworks" produces only "Communication with WiFi module failed!" error. What now???

Comment: I would appreciate a working example, so far everything fails

Comment: @Majenko, it turned out on arduino forum, that he got a MKR1000, not MKR1010

Comment: @Juraj D'oh! ...